# DATA in table goes blank when update it

Tags: php, mysql, insert

When i try to update data that comes from table , it's make blank that row in table ..

HERE IS  MY CODE:

1)edit.php (I think error on update query but  i m not sure....)

```
<?php
require("config.php");
$id =$_REQUEST['id'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bookss WHERE id = '$id'");
$test = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (!$result) 
        {
        die("Error: Data not found..");

        }

                $Title=$test['book_title'] ;
                $Author_name= $test['author_name'] ;                    
                $Mobile=$test['mobile'] ;
                $Email=$test['email'] ;
                $Publisher_name=$test['publisher_name'] ;
                $Copy_right_year =$test['copy_right_year'] ;

if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit']))
{   
    $book_save = $_POST['book_title'];
    $author_save = $_POST['author_name'];
    $mobile_save = $_POST['mobile'];
    $email_save = $_POST['email'];
    $publisher_save = $_POST['publisher_name'];
    $copy_right_save = $_POST['copy_right_year'];

    mysql_query("UPDATE bookss SET book_title ='$book_save',author_name ='$author_save',
         mobile ='$mobile_save',email ='$email_save',publisher_name ='$publisher_save',copy_right_year ='$copy_right_save' WHERE ID = '$id'")
                or die(mysql_error()); 
    echo "Saved!";

    header("Location: view.php");           
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
<html">
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Title:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $Title ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Author</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="author" value="<?php echo $Author_name ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mobile</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $Mobile ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $Email ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Publisher Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $Publisher_name ?>"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Copyright Year</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="copy" value="<?php echo $Copy_right_year ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Update" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

2)DATABASE (my database)

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `idu3`
-- Table structure for table `bookss`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookss` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `book_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `author_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `publisher_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `copy_right_year` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `bookss`
--

INSERT INTO `bookss` (`id`, `book_title`, `author_name`, `mobile`, `email`, `publisher_name`, `copy_right_year`) VALUES
(5, 'harshad heaven1', 'Harshad Patel', '8866672489', 'harshadheaven70@gmail.com', 'Friendz Company', '1990'),
(6, 'harshad heaven1', 'Harshad patel', '8866672489', 'harshadheaven70@gmail.com', 'Friendz Company', '1990'),
(7, '', '', '', '', '', ''),
(8, '', '', '', '', '', ''),
(9, '', '', '', '', '', ''),
(10, '', '', '', '', '', '');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

I am newbie.Suggestions are always welcome...

Comment: Welcome to SO; make sure to ask questions with code that's small and reproducible. You wouldn't like to wade through another's code to find the issue either.

Comment: you need to do some serious sanitizing and escaping in this code. It's ripe for an sql injection

Comment: echo your query before 'echo "Saved"'... and post here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have managed names of form fields in wrong way. You have given `name='name'` to mobile, email and publisher name fields.
2. Also you have given name as 'title' in form, but you are accessing as `$_POST['book_title']` . Same thing is with author and Copyright Year fields. Use same name as that given in form to access through POST array.

Correct these things, then it will work.

Comment: Thanx Sujit sir .. Its really very helpful .. its really very silly but again thanx BOSS..